# Создание анимации ожидания процесса в WPF

Tags: wpf, анимация

Хотел бы перенести некоторые CSS стили с сайта в приложение, чтобы иметь схожий дизайн. Пробовал создать GIF анимацию ожидания для неконтролируемого процесса, но получается достаточно увесистой и не плавной. К тому же фон не прозрачный, как в оригинале.

Сам вопрос. Возможно ли реализовать подобное в WPF и насколько это сложно?

```css
.eldr {
background-color: Black;
padding-top: 40px;
height: 120px;
}

.circle {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border: 5px solid rgba(0,174,255,0.9);
opacity: .9;
border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 50px;
box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

.circle1 {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border: 5px solid rgba(0,174,255,0.9);
opacity: .9;
border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 50px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: -50px;
-webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinPulse {
0% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
 opacity: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
}
50% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
 opacity: 1;
}
100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
 opacity: 0;
};
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
0% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
};
}
```

```html
<div class="eldr">
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ: да, возможно, не сложнее чем в CSS

Comment: Спасибо. В таком случае воспользуюсь готовым (пользовательским) ProgressRing контролом.